# Why does Amtrak tell me that my journey will last 3 hours, but also 12?

Tags: usa, trains, amtrak

I'm searching for a train from NY Penn station to Pittsburgh, on Saturday the 23rd of March. This one looks good, but it seems to say that the journey will last 12 hours, contradicting the times given more prominently. What's going on? This is clipped from Amtrak's website. [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just looked this up.  The trip you have selected is a two part trip with a change of trains in Washington DC.

The first part is the 195 Northeast Regional from Penn Station to Washington, Union Station.
This is followed by taking the 29 Capital Limited from Union Station to Pittsburgh Union station.

The 3:23 is just the NYC/DC leg trip time.  Scroll down a bit to see the 7:43 duration from DC to the 'burgh.

[image]

Comment: Ah, ok. I get it now. They could have made it clearer tho!

Comment: @NeMo You can look at the boxes that include the green "add to cart" button. Each of these boxes represent a complete journey.

Comment: @NeMo Yeah .. I had to look at it in detail before I realized what was going on.  BTW the MegaBus goes direct NYC to Pitt in less time (3 1/2 hours less).

Comment: or much better, just fly on the cheapest flight...

Comment: @xuq01 The OPs initial thoughts may have been "Sweet .. NYC to Pitt in 3 1/2 hours by train, vs 3 hours all up of dealing with airlines and airports etc". They may be re-thinking their journey now :D

Comment: @PeterM Yes, especially as none of the three NYC airports are convenient and PIT is far from downtown. But still much better than sitting 7 hrs on a bus (or 12 hrs on a train).

Comment: @PeterM: There is also a direct train once daily with a travel time of about 9 hours.

Comment: Yes, that route is going the long way via D.C., cutting 2 sides of the Philly-DC-Pitt triangle.  There should be shorter routes on the old PRR out of Philly via Harrisburg.

Comment: @NeMo When "scrolling down" is involved, that's less a matter of them failing to provide the information, and more a problem of you not reading  what they have provided.   Yes, you can argue they should make more of an effort to put it "above the fold", but *what **is** the fold* these days, with anything from 30" Retina screens  to phones? It's impossible for a web designer to design for everything.

Comment: @Harper I found the more direct route by sorting on trip length.

Comment: @Harper, your comment doesn't really seem like an attempt to be helpful. If your view is that question is trivial, the right course is to delete your comment and vote to close it. From the kind and helpful contributions of other users, I now have the information I needed in any case.

Comment: My friend had a much more extreme example of this confusion... she thought she had could book a trip from Baltimore to LA in 1 day but what she was seeing was just the first train to Chicago